# How do I address chromium slowdown following update

Tags: 13.04, updates, chromium

I've just run updates which brought Chromium up to "Version 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 13.04 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)"

Chromium is now much slower, taking 5-10 seconds in "Resolving host..." whenever a new page is accessed.

Is there any way to address this. I've looked at similar questions on google but they  refer to chrome settings not shared by this version of chromium.

Answer (score 0):

as you have mentioned That updated to a new version of chrome ,I'd wait for few more days. In mean time users like you will report the Google-chrome that new version is little bit slow and chrome dev's will release a fix for that.

So what now ?

Remove/ Disable all the installed extensions and try again. If issues still persists then its the problem with main core chrome , If not its the problem with extensions API's and you could wait for few more days so that they are going to figure it out and release some fix.

Comment: Or just downgrade ;)